# Shadow Gradle Plugin for Android

Tags: android, gradle, shadow, fatjar

Has someone had any success in using Shadow Gradle Plugin to generate AAR? I am getting an error `Could not find method shadowJar()`. This is my configuration

```
plugins {
 id 'com.android.library'
 id 'kotlin-android'
 id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '6.0.0'
}

android { ... }

shadowJar {
 baseName = 'shadow'
 classifier = ''
 archiveVersion = ''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Android, your best bet is to create your own `ShadowJar` task instance rather than trying to use the `shadowJar` extension. It will end up looking like this (e.g. `build.gradle.kts`):

```kotlin
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

 val task = project.tasks.register("yourShadowTask", ShadowJar::class.java {
    from(allJarsForRelocation)
    relocations.forEach {
        val (namespaceFrom, namespaceTo) = it
        relocate(namespaceFrom, namespaceTo)
    }
}
```

Here's a [link to a repo](https://github.com/devinmorgan/shadow-plugin-for-aar) that illustrates this in a more sophisticated manner

Answer (score -1):

Here is the right way of declaring `shadowJar` task in your `build.gradle` file:

**Apply the plugin**

```
plugins {
    ...
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "6.1.0"
}
```

**Import it**

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar
```

**Write the task**

```
task shadowJar(type: ShadowJar) {
    println("Hello from shadowJar task")
}
```